# Solve the vector-matrix equation. Minimize the length of the desired n-dimensional vector

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, vector-calculus

There is the following vector-matrix equation:

$$\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M\mathbf x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=C$$

where $C$ is a nonzero constant, $\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\end{bmatrix}^\top$ is a vector of real numbers, and $\mathbf M$ is a matrix of real numbers of dimension $n \times n$.

It is required to find a vector $\mathbf x$ that has a minimum Euclidean norm, i.e.

$$\min_{\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M\mathbf x=C}\|\mathbf x\|_2$$

1. How to solve this problem analytically within the framework of the vector-matrix apparatus?
2. How to solve this problem with optimization in Mathematica?

Comment: Note that you can replace `M` with a symmetrical matrix that gives the same result. Your solution is given by the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. You might need to think further if `C` could be negative.

Comment: Hello, mikado. Thank you for your response.
Did i understand you correctly that i need to find the eigenvectors of the matrix M and choose from them the one that corresponds to the largest eigenvalue? I would like to understand why this is so, because am i new to this section of mathematics?
Will this be a global solution?
P.S. Yes, C can be negative - why should this be taken into account?

Comment: This can be formulated as a a minimization problem with quadratic objective function and quadratic equality constraint(s). I do not think that this can be boiled down to a single linear system of equations. But it can be solved, e.g. by Newton's methos. You might want to use `FindMinimum` for that.

Comment: I have already solved this problem with the help of Mathematica optimization modules. But, i want to get an analytical solution.

Comment: In outline, a symmetric matrix can be diagonalised with an orthogonal matrix. You can easily solve the problem for a diagonal matrix. You then rotate the solution with the orthogonal matrix (giving the eigenvector mentioned above).

Comment: mikado, I see that the solution to the problem is built around operations with the matrix M? Am I interpreting your words correctly?
At the same time, I see the operations of "diagonalization" by the orthogonal matrix.
But what is “rotate the solution with the orthogonal matrix” and how does the “eigenvector mentioned above” come from, I don’t understand?
As a result, I can’t get the whole picture.
Could you show your analytical calculations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really this should have a concrete example in Mathematica copy-pastable format. Anyway, I'll show a few ways using a made-up example. We'll eventually get it down to straight linear algebra.

To keep it simple I'll assume the matrix has distinct eigenvalues. This restriction can be lifted of course. Also as has been noted in comments, without loss of generality we can assume the matrix is symmetric, since adding the transposed equation gives us an equivalent problem with a symmetric matrix. It should be mentioned that the problem need not have a solution, e.g. if the matrix is positive definite and the constant is negative. Also, multiplying through by -1 if need be, we can assume the constant is positive. Finally note that the solution is only unique up to sign.

We'll start with an example.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
c = 3;
vars = {x, y, z};
obj = vars.vars;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
symmat = mat + Transpose[mat]

(* Out[28]= {{-18, 1, 17}, {1, -20, 0}, {17, 0, -10}} *)
```

The most pedestrian thing we can do is to just invoke a minimizer directly on objective and constraint.

```
NMinimize[{obj, vars.symmat.vars == c}, vars]

(* Out[29]= {0.861901, {x -> -0.576638, y -> -0.024558, z -> -0.727177}} *)
```

We can say more than this however. In 3D (actually in general) what we are looking for is the smallest radius sphere centered at the origin that intersects with the quadric surface defined by a given level set from the quadratic form defined by the symmetric matrix. A standard thing to do is use a Lagrange multiplier formulation.

```
solns = 
  NSolve[
    Flatten[{vars.symmat.vars == c, 
      Thread[Grad[obj, vars] == 
        lambda*Grad[vars.symmat.vars, vars]]}], 
    Join[{x, y, z}, {lambda}]];
realsolns = Select[vars /. solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &]

(* Out[53]= {{-0.576638, -0.024558, -0.727177}, {0.576638, 0.024558, 
  0.727177}} *)
```

So same solution(s).

As has also been noted, one can diagonalize the system. The diagonalizing matrix will have orthogonal components hence can be made orthogonal my normalizing rows if necessary (for approximate valued matrices, `Eigensystem` does this automatically). Once we do this things get simpler. The objective function does not change since the Euclidean metric does not change under orthogonal transformation.

We diagonalize, and solve in the rotated system.

```
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[N@symmat];
{min, rvals} = 
 NMinimize[{obj, {evals.vars^2 == c, Thread[{x, y, z} >= 0]}}, {x, y, 
   z}]

(* Out[57]= {0.861901, {x -> 0., y -> 0., z -> 0.928386}} *)
```

Rotate back to recover the solution in the original coordinate system.

```
vals = Transpose[evecs].(vars /. rvals)

(* Out[58]= {0.576638, 0.024558, 0.727177} *)
```

Again the same solution (good). But now we see that the diagonalized system has a "nice" solution: it lies on a coordinate axis. That's because the primary axes of the diagonalized quadratic form are just the standard Cartesian axes. This makes things easy. We can, for example, replace the squares of the variables by new variables, reducing to linear programming (the new variables have to be positive so we'll get real square roots on back-transforming). We show this by recovering the intermediate solution above (the one prior to rotating back to the original system).

```
{min, svals} = 
 NMinimize[{Total[vars], {evals.vars == c, Thread[vars >= 0]}}, vars]
Sqrt[vars /. svals]

(*Out[62]= {0.861901, {x -> 0., y -> 0., z -> 0.861901}}

Out[63]= {0., 0., 0.928386} *)
```

But really this is all overkill. We should just observe that the minimizer has to be on a coordinate axis, and it will be the axis with the largest positive eigenvalue: coordinates corresponding to negative eigenvalues just add to the magnitude, and the ellipsoidal part of the quadric surface level set in the subspace corresponding to positive eigenvalues will be thinnest along the axis of the largest one. So we should just look at the eigenvalues.

```
evals

(* Out[64]= {-31.5177, -19.963, 3.48068} *)
```

Our only candidate is the third one since the others are negative. A bit of reasoning will show that the value for the corresponding coordinate is as below.

```
Sqrt[c/evals[[3]]]

(* Out[68]= 0.928386 *)
```

So there it is. The problem can be solved by
(1) Diagonalizing the quadratic form.
(2) Setting all but one coordinate to zero and the coordinate corresponding to the largest eigenvalue to the square root of the constant divided by that eigenvalue.
(3) Use the conversion matrix from the diagonalization to rotate back, that is, get a solution in the original system. The other solution comes from negating the solution in step (2).
All this basically just elaborates on the method posted in a comment by @mikado.

There is another thing worthy of note. The Lagrange multipliers in the system of equations are just reciprocals to the eigenvalues of the rotated system.

```
Sort[Union[lambda /. solns, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-4) &)]]

(* Out[82]= {-0.0500926, -0.0317282, 0.2873} *)

Sort[1/evals]

(* Out[83]= {-0.0500926, -0.0317282, 0.2873} *)
```

I sort of recall first encountering this connection of minimal length solutions with quadratic form constraints, and Lagrange multipliers, end eigenvalues, way back in grad school.

Comment: Wow! That's cool!
I'm so happy to see this clear example!
My next step is a good deal with this.
This method can be used if the matrix parameters and the constant C change with time (M (t) and C (t))?

Comment: It can be used for varying `C[t]`. Best I think would be to find where the eigenvalues become multiple since those values of `t` will demarcate which eigenvalue/position becomes largest (they can only cross at points of multiplicity). I guess `M[t]` can also vary for that matter. Might make the equation solving more complicated though. An alternative is to just compute for specific values of `t`, so the matrix and value are effectively constants.

Comment: And can I represent this sequence of actions in Mathematica in analytical form?

Comment: (1) Depends on exactly what you want, but certainly most can be automated. I was a bit thick about what has to be done though. For the constant it is just a matter of checking values of `t` for which it changes sign, since that determines the eigenvalues that are important.

Comment: (2) For eigenvalue multiplicity, it is the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial, as a function of the eigenvalue variable (call it `lam`) that matters. Programatically, that's `discrim=Discriminant[CharacteristicPolynomial[M[t],lam],lam]`. This gives a function of `t`, the zeros of which give points of multiplicity for the eigenvalues. So you'd find those values of `t` via `Solve[discrim==0,t]`.

Comment: (3) Last, you'll want to know when eigenvalues are zero since their sign matters as well. That's simply `Solve[Det[M[t]]==0,t]`. Now you have a bunch of important values of `t`, where all possible trnsitions can occur in terms of which eigenvalue is the largest of same magnitude as `C[t]`.

Comment: I should add that this all really belongs in the question, along with a smallish representative example. Trying to work out the details in comments is both tricky and to some extent in violation of the charter of the forum (as the moderators will soon enough tell us, I suspect).